# False is not true error?

Tags: python, class, global, specifications, definition

I'm trying to set global definitions to True, but I'm always getting an error saying "AssertionError: False is not True"

From instructions: 'Only things that are expected to be constant should be defined as globals. That is true for all of these.'

```
#global definitions
UP = True
DOWN = True
LEFT = True
RIGHT = True
dirs = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]

#a bunch of code follows here
```

This is the one of the errors (for UP) I've been getting.

```
self.assertTrue(isinstance(UP,Direction))
AssertionError: False is not true
```

I have a separate class called Direction created. Furthermore, I have to create an attribute that must be one of Up, Down, Left, and Right but I'm not sure how to do that.

attribute: value::str. Must be one of "UP", "DOWN", "LEFT", or "RIGHT".

```
#Direction class
class Direction:

    value = dirs
```

Comment: What is `Direction` and why would you expect that `UP` is of that type?

Comment: @GregHewgill It means that UP must be a Direction type.

Comment: Yes, I understand what `isinstance()` does but where in your code is there anything called `Direction`?

Comment: ```isinstance(UP, Direction)`` returns ```False```, and ```assertTrue(False)``` raises ```AssertionError```. It is not bug or error.

Comment: @GregHewgill I have a class called Definition created and I must include an attribute called value. Details updated above.

Answer (score 1):

isInstance() would return true if UP was instance of Direction. But up is not instance of Direction. it is a boolean. Hence, isinstance(UP,Direction) returns false.

Now, you are asserting that it be true. But it is not. Hence the Assertion Error, false is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `assertTrue` to `assertFalse`.

Your tests expects to run successful when the return value is `False`